# How to get mean square error in a quick way using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mean-square-error

I don't know whether this is possible or not but let me explain my question

Imagine that I have the below array

```
errors=[e1,e2,e3];
```

Now what I want to calculate is below

```
MSE=1/(array_lenght)*[e1^2+e2^2+e3^2];
```

I can make this with a loop but I wonder if there is any quick way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This finds the mean of the squared errors:

```
MSE = mean(errors.^2)
```

Each element is squared separately, and then the mean of the resulting vector is found.

Comment: can you tell me what does "." means just before ^

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG It squares each element separately, so that `[1 2 3].^2 == [1 4 9]`. If you leave the dot out, Matlab squares the whole matrix, which won't work since it isn't a square. You also use `.*` for element-wise multiplication of matrices.

Answer (score 3):

```
sum(errors.^2) / numel(errors)
```

Answer (score 1):

Raising powers and adding can be done together instead of sequentially:

```
MSE = (errors*errors') / numel(errors)
```