# Fit data with a numerical ode solution (on Matlab)

Tags: matlab, optimization, solver, ode, data-fitting

I am looking for a way to fit my experimental data by a theoretical model which is described by a non-linear differential equation.

Unfortunately this latter can only be solved numerically (by solving this second degree, non-linear differential equation).

I manage to solve the differential equation for a set of parameters using the ode45 Matlab solver but now I want to find the proper fit parameters of the model. Also, I may have to mention that my ode45 is initiated at `z=zmax` (max being large so I can assume it is infinity) by `y(zmax)=y0` and `yprime(zmax)=yprime0` and I solve backward (from zmax to z=0).

I am quite new to this kind of numerical problems, are there classical ways to solve such problems?

Does anyone knows if there is a Matlab procedure which would help me solve this? On which principles is it based/constructed? (if possible I'd like to know the theoretical trick to solve this problem in a smart way, not by trying all the possible sets of parameters which would be very time consuming (I have 5 fit parameters!).

Thank you for your precious help!

Comment: Please, be more specific. Share code, the equation and so on. It would help in searching the solution.

Comment: I would suggest to make the conversion t  = 1/(z-1) so that time goes from 0 to 1, although without seeing the equation it is hard to know whether this may cause numerical problems. In any case you are probably trying to do a least squares fit - just put the output of your ODE as a function of your params into lsqnonlin in matlab http://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html ), if you want gradients, you might need to get a little fancier - check out the adjoint method for ODEs / Optimal Control, although for 5 parameters brute force finite-differencing might suffice

Answer (score 1):

You have facy methods in the [Optimization Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/optimization/). In case you don't have access to it, you could do it manually by:

- Selecting a [cost function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) between the experimental and model data. For example, [mean-squared-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298236/how-to-get-mean-square-error-in-a-quick-way-using-matlab).
- Doing [heuristic optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization#Heuristics) of the cost function. For example, [Nelder-Mead method](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2181-numerical-methods-using-matlab-2e/content/edition2/matlab/chap_8/nelder.m).

Comment: Nelder-Mead does not really work except in flashy 2D examples where everything is convex and smooth. There are other, better derivative-free methods, but it is not  too difficult to compute the derivative of an ODE trajectory.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you for the info. Which derivative-free method would you recommend?

Comment: My impression is based on this talk coral.ie.lehigh.edu/~katyas/wp-content/talks/ISMP2012-3.pptx and some others at ISMP 2012. Basically, you get back to building quadratic models from limited data and apply a trust-region approach.